# TypeScript Dynamic Type Checking

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to know how to dynamically check type in TypeScript without using variable.
Here I check the type of "special data" to be SpecialType with variable. How can I do it without variable?

```
interface Params {
   [key in keyof something]: {
       param: string
       else: any
   }
}

const somethingSpecial: SpecialType = {...special data}

const variable: Params = {
   param1: {
      param: 'some string',
      else: 123  // some any type
   },
   param2: {
      param: 'another string',
      else: somethingSpecial  // does not want it to be any
   },
}
```

I tried this:

```
 else: {...wrong data} as SpecialType 
// or
 else: <SpecialType>{...wrong data}
```

this makes it valid, even if the data is wrong.
This parses the special data to SpecialType. I do not want it to parse, I want it to check the type.

Answer (score 0):

you can just define your Params as

```js
interface Params {
   [key in keyof something]: {
       param: string
       else: any
   },
   param2: {
       param: string
       else: SpecialType
   }
}
```

if you do not want to edit your params type, you could just use intersection types like so:

```js
const variable: Params & { param2: {name: string, else: SpecialType} } = ...
```

this works as in this case the key param2 is more specific than the generic case, so the specific key is prefered over the more generic one.